# Laravel required_if validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate the **cost** field. If the **activity_code** value is other than "SE". It can be any value but not SE.

```
$rules = [
'cost' => 'required_if:activity_code,null',
'select_plans' => 'required_if:activity_code,SE',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = [
'cost' => 'required_unless:prf_activity_code,!=,SE',
'select_plans' => 'required_if:activity_code,SE',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use:

```
$rules = [
'cost' => 'required_unless:activity_code,SE',
'select_plans' => 'required_if:activity_code,SE',
];
```

or

```
$rules = [
'cost' => 'required_if:activity_code,!=,SE',
'select_plans' => 'required_if:activity_code,SE',
];
```